# In GNOME is there a way to focus/activate a window on mouse over?

Tags: linux, mouse, gnome, fedora

I recall a partner in a CS class who changed my setup to focus a window on mouse over and that was really handy for programming with a ton of terminals open.

I've seen Dwell Click under accessibility options, but that doesn't seem to do anything.  I know that sometimes the GUI control applets have features undisabled that don't really do anything (i.e. WINS) if you don't have the right stuff installed.

How do I get mouse over pretty much just simulate clicking the window.

(Using Fedora 14 with GNOME)

Comment: Just deleted my main answer as I misunderstood your question the first few times through. It's called "Raise selected windows after an interval" in System/Preferences/windows, but raising only on title bar is not implemented to my knowledge(I could be wrong).

Comment: @Dan M. That's the answer I was looking for, it's not under "Mouse" it's under "Windows".  I had a problem where it said 
"Window manager "compiz" has not registered a configuration tool", all I had to do to rid myself of that was metacity --replace.

Comment: Made that the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasted from comment above ^^

Just deleted my main answer as I misunderstood your question the first few times through. It's called "Raise selected windows after an interval" in System/Preferences/windows, but raising only on title bar is not implemented to my knowledge(I could be wrong)

Comment: Yeah, that worked too, just installed gconf-editor, never knew that existed before thanks.

Comment: No worries, that is nice little tool to muck things up real good :)

Answer (score 5):

Run gnome-tweak-tool.

Go to the **Windows** tab and change the **Focus Mode** to either *Sloppy* or *Mouse*.

For further details:

Install dconf-editor

Run dconf-editor

Navigate to org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences and check the other Focus options: focus-new-windows, auto-raise and raise-on-click. You can see a nice description

Answer (score 1):

What used to be `gnome-tweak-tool` is now `gnome-tweaks`

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
dnf install gnome-tweaks # if under Fedora or Alma Linux
gnome-tweaks
```

[Gnome Tweaks UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFgYs.png)

As you can see the "windows" menu gives you the option to focus on hover. I'm using it on my machine and love it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).